# Reusing LUKS master key file to decrypt partition at boot

Tags: fedora, luks, disk-encryption, cryptsetup

I'm reusing a hard drive from a laptop in a small form factor PC. The PC is an occasionally used computer, with nothing but sleeping VMs, that I connect to to over RDP. The computer is powered down most of the time. I can wake it up over LAN and then wake up the VMs that I need. The problem is, that when I re-used the laptop hard drive, I simply booted it, did updates to Fedora 31 and kept using it.

The SSD has two partitions: `sda1` is `/boot`, and `sda2`is a LUKS volume containing `/`, `/home`, and a swap partition.
The problem is, that when I boot the computer from the network, it asks for the passphrase to decrypt `/dev/sda2`.

Here's `lsblk`:

```
NAME                                          MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda                                             8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk  
├─sda1                                          8:1    0   500M  0 part  /boot
└─sda2                                          8:2    0 465.3G  0 part  
  └─luks-151aef9f-a994-4495-a532-63899b1720d4 253:0    0 465.3G  0 crypt 
    ├─fedora_patchtop-root                    253:1    0    50G  0 lvm   /
    ├─fedora_patchtop-swap                    253:2    0   3.9G  0 lvm   [SWAP]
    └─fedora_patchtop-home                    253:3    0 411.4G  0 lvm   /home
sr0                                            11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

As you can see, `/dev/sda1` which contains `/dev/boot` is *not* encrypted.

I wish I could get rid of the passphrase prompt at boot, as this computer isn't used in an environment anymore where I need hard disk encryption, rather I need unattended boot capabilities.

Now, `/dev/sda2` has one key slot in use (slot 0).

The first thing I did, was to dump the key file like this:

```
cryptsetup luksDump /dev/sda2 --dump-master-key --master-key-file master.key
```

I've then put `master.key` in `/boot`, so it's available on an unencrypted partition:

```
-r--------. 1 root root 64 Apr 18 10:15 /boot/master.key
```

Now on to `/etc/crypttab`.
My crypttab only had one line, that looked like this:

```
luks-151aef9f-a994-4495-a532-63899b1720d4 UUID=151aef9f-a994-4495-a532-63899b1720d4 none
```

I changed this to:

```
luks-151aef9f-a994-4495-a532-63899b1720d4 UUID=151aef9f-a994-4495-a532-63899b1720d4 /boot/master.key luks,initramfs
```

Finally, I created a new initramfs with dracut like this:

```
dracut -vfN
```

However, after a reboot, I'm still asked for the password.

I also tried making a new keyfile, and using this as key for slot 1 of the LUKS setup, it still kept asking me for the password I should enter manually. However I'm unsure whether it kept asking me for the password because slot 0 was still the manual password, and it just started from the top, etc.

For reference, here are the UUIDs of my partitions, should this be important:

```
NAME                                          UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                                  
├─sda1                                        43f00ca0-60d2-4c20-9b20-4ec914c575cf   /boot
└─sda2                                        151aef9f-a994-4495-a532-63899b1720d4   
  └─luks-151aef9f-a994-4495-a532-63899b1720d4 RlyNgN-3ca3-cqvW-iljT-meWT-eqTO-h02Xh6 
    ├─fedora_patchtop-root                    60a53d2a-db9b-47be-991f-cdbdcfd8e72d   /
    ├─fedora_patchtop-swap                    ef05de8f-cd1e-4491-b837-80656b91dc60   [SWAP]
    └─fedora_patchtop-home                    7b457fab-02a9-40f9-a22b-e0c16be2f137   /home
```

---

***edit***

I tried one more thing:

First, I created a dead-simple passphrase:

```
cryptsetup luksAddKey /dev/sda2 --force-password
```

The password is actually blank. The main reason was, that if I get stuck at this point, I just need to press the return key at the passphrase prompt.
This works rather well.

Next, I added the aforementioned key into slot 0:

```
cryptsetup luksChangeKey /dev/sda2 /boot/master.key --key-slot 0
```

The main reason I did this, is because I read in cryptsetup's man page, that key slots are checked in order. So slot 0, then slot 1, etc. I thought that perhaps it's still asking for my passphrase, because that's slot 0. So, I used the key file for slot 0, such that the password is the *second* option in slot 1.

And again, I generated a new initramfs and rebooted, but no cigar. It still asks for a password, however this time, just hitting return is enough to make it boot.

The situation, however, is still not satisfactory. I still need to press enter/return at the passphrase prompt in order to get the system to boot. This requires me to at least have a keyboard attached to the machine, but the idea is, that it's pretty much entirely headless. So no monitor and no keyboard.